# Inverse of absolute value function?

Tags: graphing-functions, absolute-value

I am graphing a square with the following equation:

$$|y|=1-|x|$$

[image]

However, I need the equation in terms of y. That is, the form `y=f(x)` as opposed to the current `|y|=f(x)`

How do you get an equation in terms of y when absolute value is wrapping it. Is there an inverse absolute value function I can apply to both sides of the equation?

---

My first attempt was to use the old trick: $|n| = \sqrt[2]{n^2}$

But of course that's not a real equation since roots have $±$.

Sure enough when applying that to try to get the equation in terms of y the graph failed to reproduce a square and ended up graphing what looked like a 'w'.

[image]

Comment: This isn't a function, so the only way to do it would be piecewise-ish.

Comment: @Randall I wonder if there is a way to do it without going piecewise. I am currently experimenting with converting absolute value to this form $|y| \rightarrow y\cdot sgn(y)$

Comment: But sgn(y) is also piecewise... run into same problem.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw It is not possible.  A single $x$ creates two different $y$s (generally), so there is no way to make this function-like.

Comment: @coffeemath I made a trig function to account for that. $sgn(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} tanh(x\cdot k)$

Comment: Would writing the equation in polar coordinates be acceptable?

Comment: @Andrei I need cartesian for this unfortunately

Comment: Then the answer is no, since you have two branches. That's similar to the equation of a circle $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: @Andrei Yet with a circle you can go to terms of `y`:  $y=±\sqrt[2]{1-x^2}$

Comment: Then this is similar $y=\pm(1-|x|)$. See the answer below from @RobertIsrael.

Comment: It occurs to me that absolute value is a form of a hash function is a sense. Data is lost. You can’t unlose data anymore than you can undo a hash function. Since abs(-3) = abs(3) you can’t work backwards from 3 and know if it came from a -3 or a 3 therefor it is indeed impossible

Answer (score 6):

$y = \pm |y| = \pm (1 - |x|)$ for $-1 \le x \le 1$.

That is, there are two cases: $+(1 - |x|)$ which gives you the top half of your square, and $-(1-|x|)$ which gives you the bottom half.

Those inequalities are necessary, because $|y|$ is not allowed to be negative.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for something unbounded but this will have to do for now. +1

Comment: You cannot do any better, and this still is not of the form $y=f(x)$ that you originally asked for, because that's impossible.  The answer here is the best possible, but please do not think it is a *function*.

Comment: @randall you’re getting too caught up on the word “function”. I’m aware function isn’t the correct term, however this answer is sufficient for the use-case I have. I’m leaving the question open for now to see what else others may come up with

Comment: What do you mean "something unbounded"?  The square is bounded!